# SQL query with foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle10g

I need some help writing an SQL query.  I am not sure how to put it in words so the best way for me to show you what I want is with an example.  (I am using Oracle 10)

I have 2 tables:

```
Employees (2 fields):
e_id    e_name
 1       Joe
 2       Tom
 3       Fred

Duties (2 fields)
e_id    e_duty
1       'Clean Floor'
1       'Paint Walls'
2       'Lawn care'
3       'Walk Dog'
3       'Paint Fence'
3       'Cook Dinner'
```

The results that I'm trying to get follows:

```
Joe   'Clean Floor'      'Paint Walls'
Tom   'Lawn Care'
Fred  'Walk Dog'         'Paint Fence'        'Cook Dinner'
```

How can I write a query to get the desired results?  Also if there is a name for this type of query, please let me know.  I'm sure someone out there has already done things like this before, but I just didn't know what it was called thus not knowing what to search for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all the duties in separate columns this is almost impossible unless there's a known upper limit. I would use a PIVOT query if that's the case.

If you don't mind them all being in the same column you could do something like this:

```
select name, wm_concat(e_duty)
  from employees e
  join duties d
    on e.e_id = d.e_id
 group by name
```

WM_CONCAT() is not supported but is available ([there are plenty of other string aggregation techniques though](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques.php#wm_concat))

If you did have an upper limit on the number of duties you had (or wanted to return) then the pivot query would look something like this:

```
select e_name, "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"
  from employees e
  join ( select e_id, duty
              , row_number() over ( partition by e_id order by 1 ) as r
           from duties ) d
    on e.e_id = d.e_id
 pivot ( max(duty) for r in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 )
          )
```

The ROW_NUMBER() is there only to generate an easy key to use as the duty itself could be anything.

Comment: I actually do have an upper limit in my real world scenario.  6 is the most duties an employee can have.

Comment: In that case what I've done with the PIVOT will work; I've just updated it to be exactly the same as your requirements @user1031516.